# How can I set an Icon for the Application Manifest? C#

Tags: c#, icons, publish

I have an application that I have published. I have already set an icon in the properties f the project. But I noticed that the application manifest still have the default icon displayed. I would like to change that icon into the icon I have made.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on project => click on properties, in property window chose Application tab
then select "Icon and manifest" option button now chose icon for your project.